# In the event of an attack on a city such as Chicago, how long would it take the US military to respond?

Tags: military, teleportation

Assuming that the attacker was able to travel unnoticed or possibly used something like teleportation, how long would it take the military to arrive for a counteroffensive? If possible, I'd like time estimates along with force strength.

**More details for this hypothetical**

- Fast moving advanced military (100k soldiers)
- Clearly more advanced than most or all nations that are known on earth.
- All matter of abilities including air, land, and sea (great lakes).

Comment: What kind of attacker?  ("The" attacker sounds like terrorism.)

Comment: @RonJohn My line of thinking was a secretly  advanced nation or extra/ultra terrestrial.

Comment: How many attackers?  What are they attacking with?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. We'll need a bit more information about your scenario. How big and severe is the threat? Are we talking a few soldiers? An entire army? What sort of weapons? Tanks? Aircraft?

Comment: What kind of force-strength are we talking? Hundreds or thousands of "Infantry?" Armor? Aircraft? What are they doing? Are they leveling everything in sight? Taking and holding a single building?

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to Worldbuilding! This is an interesting question, but it’s currently a bit too broad. We’ll need to know details like the size and method of the attack, what the damage is, and whether or not these attackers are able to cover up or hide any of the damage, perhaps by blocking communications. Can I recommend that you bounce this question over to our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), where you can get feedback on it before it’s actually posted?

Comment: Aliens? Paratroopers? Invaders from the future? Invaders from the past? Orcs through a portal? I have to vote to close as "unclear what you are asking."

Comment: What do you mean by counteroffensive? 9/11 and Pearl Harbor took months to have a "counterattack", and did not use teletransportation

Comment: Sounds like [Red Dawn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Qc8jJ0TjSY), ([the good one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_I4WgBfETc)), but with teleportation and aliens.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Chris. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. This question appears to lack criteria to help narrow the set of applicable answers to discern an objectively "best" answer. As such, it may be put on hold until a clarifying edit is made. If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986) to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: The problem here is that an answer can guess the time for a tank, plane, missile to get to Chicago. But the real time waster would be the time needed to realize that something is happening in Chicago, that there are foreign troops involved, that local law enforcement had been beaten, to verify reports and assess the nature, strength and objectives of the enemy, to pass all the information through a disbelieving chain of command... And for that it is almost impossible to give a guess.

Comment: Hello Chris.  I had to vote off-topic:too story-based (OT:TSB) because you're not asking about the rules of your world (our site focus), but the reaction of world elements to a situation (story building).  If an answer depends on the plot of your story (which this does) and not the rules of your world, it's off-topic here.

Comment: The issue is not how quickly can the military get to any city, but how long would it take for the government to authorize the move.  Even just to activate the National Guard for an emergency like blizzards, there's a very specific series of steps that need taking.  I don't have the details at hand, but twelve hours just to get authorization would not be impossible. They you'd go with the guesses of how fast the soldiers and armor could deploy. If I can find the steps and timeframe, I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since the term "counter-offensive" was used, I'll assume a sort of [Red Dawn scenario](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Qc8jJ0TjSY) ([the good one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_I4WgBfETc)), but with teleportation. A major and superior hostile army of unknown origin suddenly appears in Chicago and begins attacking outward.

The [National Response Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Response_Framework) would be activated to coordinate effort. [NSPD 51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_and_Homeland_Security_Presidential_Directive) would also be activated, most of which is classified. An attempt would be made to organize the evacuation of Chicago, but it would likely result in the biggest traffic jam in history.

While the US is prepared for smaller attacks, terrorist attacks, or nuclear attack, it is not prepared for a large, well-equipped hostile land army suddenly appearing simply because there's no way it could happen outside of sci-fi. While there are various forces ready to respond immediately, these small units would not last long against an attack of this scale.

The first organized resistance would be 12,000 officers of the Chicago Police, plus surrounding departments. The governor would activate the Illinois National Guard and ask for help from the Federal government and the surrounding areas. Elements of the Illinois National Guard would arrive soon after, specifically the [178th Infantry Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/178th_Infantry_Regiment_(United_States)) in Chicago itself. The [Illinois Air National Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illinois_Air_National_Guard) has no combat units. If things are desperate enough [Naval Station Great Lakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Station_Great_Lakes), a US Navy training facility, might get involved.

[United States Army North](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_North) is charged with the protection of the United States. The major challenge is not distance, but readiness. Its [combat units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army#Combat_maneuver_organizations) are not on ready combat status. They would need some time to call in their troops, get their equipment out of storage, come up with transportation and operational plans, and get everything organized for transport. Fortunately transport over land is much simpler to organize than over the ocean and they could probably do it in days rather than weeks. Actually then driving to Chicago is fairly easy due to it being very well connected by road and rail.

The first major combat units available would likely be elements of cavalry, airborne, and Marine units which are more mobile and "expeditionary" in nature. Fortunately for Chicago, none of these units are currently deployed. 10-15 years ago a significant portion of the US military would have been busy in [Iraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_War) and [Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Afghanistan_(2001%E2%80%93present)).

- [XVIII Airborne Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XVIII_Airborne_Corps)

  - [3rd Infantry Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3rd_Infantry_Division_(United_States)) (Georgia)
  - [10th Mountain Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10th_Mountain_Division) (as light infantry) (New York)
  - [82nd Airborne Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/82nd_Airborne_Division) (as light infantry) (North Carolina)
  - [101st Airborne Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101st_Airborne_Division) (as light infantry) (Kentucky)
- [I Marine Expeditionary Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Marine_Expeditionary_Force) (California)
- [II Marine Expeditionary Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/II_Marine_Expeditionary_Force) (North Carolina)
- [1st Cavalry Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Cavalry_Division_(United_States)) (Texas)
- [3rd Cavalry Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3rd_Cavalry_Regiment_(United_States)) (Texas)

Elements of the heavier units would arrive in the days and weeks to come. National Guard units would be nationalized into the US Army. Reserve units would also be activated, though they will take weeks to gather their men and equipment and organize, adding some 200,000 more soldiers. Additional units would likely be recalled from overseas taking a month or more.

Meanwhile [USAF Air Combat Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Combat_Command) would organize its continental air forces. [First Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Air_Force) is charged with defense of the continental US, plus the [Eastern Air Defense Sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Air_Defense_Sector). This is primarily Air National Guard (ANG) fighter wings operating F-16 fighter-bombers. The closest are likely...

- [115th Fighter Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/115th_Fighter_Wing) of the Wisconson ANG in Madison about 150 miles away.
- [180th Fighter Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180th_Fighter_Wing) of the Ohio ANG in Toledo about 250 miles away.
- [148th Fighter Wing](https://military.wikia.com/wiki/148th_Fighter_Wing) of the Minnesota Air National Guard in Duluth about 400 miles away
- [138th Fighter Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/138th_Fighter_Wing) of the Oklahoma ANG in Tulsa about 600 miles away.

[Heavy bomber units of B-52s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_B-52_Units_of_the_United_States_Air_Force#Current_USAF_B-52_units) and [B-1 units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_B-1_units_of_the_United_States_Air_Force) have the range to fly directly from their bases around the country as soon as they are ready. All 19 active B-2s are part of the [509th Bomb Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/509th_Bomb_Wing) in nearby Missouri. These expensive and limited assets are unlikely to be committed until there is more information about the threat.

The [24th Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-Fourth_Air_Force) would also mobilize for cybersecurity and the [25th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-Fifth_Air_Force) for intelligence and recon.

More wings would respond as they organize and tanker assets become available. If the battle goes on long enough aircraft from [the Boneyard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/309th_Aerospace_Maintenance_and_Regeneration_Group) would be reactivated.

US Navy carriers are normally the US's fire brigades, but no US carriers will be appearing on the Great Lakes. The locks of the Saint Lawrence Seaway can accommodate up to 740 ft, but a [Nimitz class carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Lawrence_Seaway) is over 1000 ft and the [Wasps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasp-class_amphibious_assault_ship) are over 800. Instead, their ready air wings may be forward deployed on land.

All of the Navy's destroyers, cruisers, and littoral combat ships (except the [Independence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence-class_littoral_combat_ship) which is too fat) could make the trip to provide fire support, intelligence, and anti-air. In addition, Chicago is in range of [Tomahawk cruise missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomahawk_(missile)) launched from New York Harbor.

Comment: Under article 5 of the NATO treaty other NATO countries forces would also deploy to add the effort. Canadian troops and air assets the British have Tomahawk capable submarines for example.

Comment: @Sarriesfan That's a very good point, I was just thinking about that last night. I doubt they'd be early responders, things would have to get pretty bad before the US govt to allowed foreign troops and combat aircraft on US soil.

Answer (score 1):

Here is list of various military bases in Illinois:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_military_bases_in_Illinois
You can also look up Wisconsin and Indiana, they are very close.

Research what they have, and think about how fast they can get it to Chicago. 
I'd say give them anywhere from half-hour for limited deployment, and a few hours for rolling out 50% of their gear.

Then search for airbases in the US, and estimate flight time.

**Edit:** Let's take Naval Station Great Lakes for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Station_Great_Lakes 
Mainly a training facility, with up to 7,000 enrolled at the installation at any time. I'd say they arm at least couple thousands of them with small arms and get them to downtown Chicago on trucks or busses in couple hours, and the rest over several more hours.

In general, I would not expect too many battle-ready troops or heavy weaponry near Chicago. It is surrounded by thousands of miles of friendly land. Any conventional force moving to Chicago will be detected long before it gets there, and US military probably does not expect teleporting enemies.

I am sure there are extensive anti-air and anti-missile capabilities, so if they are useful against your force, they can deployed in minutes.

**Edit 2:** First response will be National Guard. They have armories in the city: http://www.il.ngb.army.mil/Organizations/Army/Cities/Chicago.aspx
I would not expect heavy armor, but Humvees with their usual weapons are definitely there. 
They probably have several thousand personnel living in the city, and organizational structure to mobilize them on a short notice. They could use same armories to arm cadets from Naval Academy that I mentioned above, and any other non-combat military personnel in the area.

So expect a few thousand soldiers, with Humvees, in couple hours.

Which might not sound like a lot, but military are really planning for riots or national disasters, not teleporting super-troopers.

Comment: This was a useful post, but it technically doesn't answer the question.  I recommend you pick one base and use it as an example of how to use the info you're providing.

Comment: "here is a link, do your research" is not an answer.

Comment: don't forget the "used something like teleportation"

Answer (score 0):

**For an American City in general:** Anywhere from minutes to months.

There are aircraft flying over the USA at all times, and with the proper authorization they can blow their load on any unwelcome visitor. I would imagine that the airforce has a very detailed (and very classified) set of documents outlining how and when to do that.

When Islamic terrorists have attacked military bases inside the United States, they have normally been killed in less than an hour.

For a military unit to roll out and start fighting inside the borders of the USA would require approval from either the president or the state governor (each with a clear chain of succession in case they are killed.).

**For Chicago:** Never.

It has no strategic value. Even for Americans, it is almost ungovernable. You will find many comparisons of Chicago and Baghdad that show Chicago to be the more violent city.

Launching a counter-attack inside of Chicago puts all of its residents at huge risk of collateral damage, so either a lot of American civilians die, or the military fights under restrictive rules of engagement which may render them ineffective.

An invader would need to garrison tens of thousands - perhaps hundreds of thousands of soldiers to control the city. They would have to feed nearly 3 million people on their own supply lines. To break out of Chicago in any direction, they have to cross 1,000 miles of flat, open terrain with the entire might of the USAF bombing them to dust.

tldr: If someone invaded Chicago, we would probably let them keep it.

Comment: Worldbuilding is not for political commentary.

Comment: @Schwern His politics aside he raises an interesting point - Chicago isn't a good place to break out from. Any significant force moving over land would get absolutely slammed by the USAF. Once it's clear that they're fighting an army and not some terrorist cell, containment and preventing further intrusion would be top priority, especially since Chicago isn't a huge strategic asset.

Comment: what, exactly, are my politics?

Comment: @James The uncomfortable truth that south-side chicago is a complete writeoff. Like Schewrn said, worldbuilding isn't for politics.

Comment: Chicago is not a major military asset, but it is important for economy: it is a transport hub (link from Mississipi to Great Lakes), and home to major commodity exchanges that will disrupt banks, manufacturing and farming if they fall.

Comment: "*When Islamic terrorists have attacked military bases inside the United States...*" [There haven't been any that I'm aware of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Islamist_terrorist_attacks). [Plenty of other shootings though](https://www.nbcwashington.com/news/local/A-History-of-Shootings-at-Military-Installations-in-the-US-223933651.html).

Comment: You forgot to mention the Chicago style pizza...

Comment: Your answer is rather self contradictory. If the city has no value as you state, why should collateral damage be a concern?